# Binary Tree Visualization - circular tree? (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, binary-tree, visualization, qgraphicsview

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on implementing an algorithm for creating a circular 'phylogenetic' type:

[image]

graphics scene for a binary tree in QT? Something like this:

[image]

except with the word labels replaced with buttons.

I'm currently using [QT Elastic Nodes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html) as a template, and have managed to create a standard tree visualization with dynamically set distances

[image].

But wanted to switch to a circular format like the link above, if possible.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You say: *I'm currently using QT Elastic Nodes as a template, and have managed to create a standard tree visualization with dynamically set distances*, so we ask you to show it to see where it can be corrected so that you get what you want .

Comment: If I would go through this, I  will first search for any existing open source libraries because it saves time and sure money.
When i see this post i thought you are declaring a new project or asking a question this sounds you are declaring a project and you should pay.
but , if you are looking for a start point [Graphviz](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/) is my offer and [here](http://www.mupuf.org/blog/2010/07/08/how_to_use_graphviz_to_draw_graphs_in_a_qt_graphics_scene/) is brief usage explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are looking for is either the circular or the radial phylogenetic layout variant devised by Bachmaier, Brandes and Schlieper. You can find their publication at the publisher's website [doi:10.1007/11602613_110](https://doi.org/10.1007/11602613_110) or just google for the freely available PDF. You can also get an overview of other radial layouts at [treevis.net](http://treevis.net/) by setting the filters at the top to "2D", "explicit", and "radial".

Comment: Could you please mention that algorithm here? Just put a reference to that one below.

Comment: It is a variant of the weighted version of Tutte’s barycentric layout algorithm. But I'm not sure if that helps you much. Just take a look at the paper I posted above, or one of the many [PDFs](https://www.infosun.fim.uni-passau.de/~chris/down/DrawingPhyloTreesEA.pdf) of it that lie around the internet...